# Aircraft Fuel Calculator Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I'm fairly new to python and am looking for suggestions on a project to calculate fuel for flying.  The requirements for calculating output is putting it as "Flight time: x hours and x minutes".

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get my calculated hours broken down to display that. Below is the code I've gotten so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# display a title
print("Aircraft Fuel Calculator")
print()

choice = "y"
while choice == "y":

    # get user entry
    distance_nautical_miles = float(input("Distance in nautical miles: "))             

    # calculate results
    flight_time = float((distance_nautical_miles /  120) * 60)
    required_fuel = (((flight_time / 60) + .5) * 8.4)
    hours = float(flight_time / 60)
    #mins

    # display the results
    print("Flight time: ", hours, "hour(s)", "and", flight_time, "minute(s)" )
    print("Required fuel: ", round(required_fuel, 1), "gallons")
    print()

    choice = input("Continue? (y/n): ")    
    print()

print("Bye!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
flight_time = float((distance_nautical_miles /  120) * 60)
```

Presumably that formula yields the total number of minutes.

Then you can *integer divide* by 60 to get the number of hours, and *modulo* by 60 to get the remaining number of minutes:

```
hours = flight_time // 60
minutes = flight_time % 60
```

Comment: worked like a charm.  Thanks for your quick response!